# Asp.net core - How to implement realtime using signalR

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, signalr

I am adding a comments part in my project, I would like to use real-time using signalR.
I'm using Ajax for adding comments, and I want to refresh data for all users after the comment inserts into the database.

**This is my code in Razor view :**

```
  <form asp-action="SendComment" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-subId="@Model.Subject.Id"
                asp-route-AccountName="@User.Identity.Name" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">
                            <textarea name="comment" id="myTextbox" required class="form-control mb-3" rows="3" cols="1" placeholder="اكتب هنا"></textarea>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <button type="submit" id="myBtn" class="btn bg-blue-400 btn-labeled btn-labeled-right ml-auto"><b><i class="icon-paperplane"></i></b> ارسال</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**Ajax code :**

```
jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
try {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.action,
        data: new FormData(form),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.isValid) {
                $('#view-all').html(res.html)
            }
            else
                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
    //to prevent default form submit event
    return false;
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
}
```

}

**signalR code (*Not finished*)**

```
<reference path="../lib/signalr/browser/signalr.js" />
```

$(() => {
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/signalServer").build();

```
connection.start();

connection.on("refreshData", function () {
    loadData();
});

loadData();

function loadData() {
    debugger;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',

        url: '@Url.Action("refreshComments","Home")',
        success: function (res) {
            $('#view-all').html(res);
        }
    })

}
```

});

**Code-behind :**

```
 var newComment = new CourseComment
                    {
                        Comment = comment,
                        Date = DateTime.Now,
                        ApplicationUser = user,
                        SubjectId = subId,
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                    };
                    _courseCommnt.Entity.Insert(newComment);
                    await _courseCommnt.SaveAsync();

                    await _signalR.Clients.All.SendAsync("refreshData");

                    _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("تم ارسال التعليق بنجاح");

                    var courseComments = await _courseCommnt.Entity.GetAll().Include(a => a.ApplicationUser)
                        .Where(a => a.SubjectId == subId).OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

                    var vm = new HomeViewModel
                    {
                        CourseComments = courseComments
                    };

                    return Json(new
                    {
                        isValid = true,
                        html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_SubjectComments", vm)
                    });
```

Comment: And what is the problem? You have to ask a question here

Comment: My question is How to refresh data for all users after the comment posted @TimurUmerov

Comment: You can use SignalR and SQL Dependency to display database update notifications, please refer to the following article：https://forums.asp.net/t/2128080.aspx?Problem+when+i+upload+image+with+Jquery+ajax+Bootstrap+Modal+